# SFDC shall have a validation to not allow change of Customer Program's status if it is set to active once

Tags: validation

I mean When record is created with status field=active,inactive,terminated.It should be saved,but when we do update status field 4m active to inactive/terminated,it should throw error.
Means once status is in active mode,if change the mode active to inactive/terminated,It should fire error.

This is the rule that I tried to write and it does not work

```
AND (
     PRIORVALUE(Status__c) = "Active", 
     ISCHANGED(Status__c)
)
```

Comment: AND ( PRIORVALUE(Status__c) = "Active", ISCHANGED(Status__c) )                              I used above rule but its not working

Comment: I got it by using below rule AND(ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status__c),"Active"),NOT(ISNEW()), 
ISCHANGED(Status__c) )

Answer (score 0):

When using PRIORVALUE() function with a picklist, you still need to use the TEXT() or ISPICKVAL() function along with it.  Try something like this

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status__c), "Active"),
    ISCHANGED(Status__c)
)
```

Comment: I also used similar rule ,but its not working

Comment: Can you tell me what you mean by its not working.  Is there an error, or you are getting unexpected results?